LocalHostName change doesn't stick for Apple Remote Desktop on macOS Sonoma
In the sharing pane of System Preferences (or with scutil --set LocalHostName) you can change the Bonjour name. I have done this and in Terminal this works, scutil --get LocalHostName shows the new LocalHostname.
But Apple Remote Desktop on other systems keeps seeing the old Bonjour name. Several reboots etc. haven't helped.
Any tips how I can get this fixed?
